# Integers with exactly three factor pairs whose successors are relatively prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, factorization

I am interested in the following problem, and will appreciate pointers around how it can be solved – partially or fully – and/or indicators around whether it is even tractable:

> Characterize $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with exactly three distinct factor pairs $(a,b)$ for which $\gcd(a+1,b+1) = 1$.

**Background** (unnecessary for the question; included only for interest's sake – if any!):

The context is related to the [**Frobenius number**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNumber.html) generated by two positive integers. It is a well-known fact that for positive integers $x,y$ such that $\gcd(x,y) = 1$, their Frobenius number is $xy - x - y = (x-1)(y-1) - 1$.

In exploring a [**friendlier version**](https://playwithyourmath.com/2017/07/27/3-chicken-nuggets/) of this problem with a high school class, we noted that, for example, there are three different pairs (up to symmetry) that have a Frobenius number of $11$; specifically,

$(x-1)(y-1) = 12$ has factor pairs yielding the solutions: $x = 2, y = 13$; $x = 3, y = 7$; and $x = 4, y = 5$.

**So**, we wondered: What are Frobenius numbers besides $11$ that can be generated by precisely three distinct pairs? This wonder is equivalent to the problem above.

The difficulty we ran into is that when searching for three factor pairs by rigging up numbers with six factors, i.e., numbers with a prime factorization of $p^2 q$ or $p^5$, the factor pair successors thus listed were not always relatively prime.

For example, $2^2 \cdot 3 - 1 = 11$ corresponds to the earlier example; $3^2 \cdot 2 - 1 = 17$ also satisfies the criteria. Unfortunately, when we tried $2^2 \cdot 7 - 1 = 27$, the factor pairs for $28$ ran into trouble: e.g. $28 = 2 \cdot 14$, but the successors have $\gcd(3,15) \neq 1$. And, therefore, $3$ and $15$ do not even have a (well-defined) Frobenius number.

> **RE: Comments** I (on behalf of our class!) am amenable to any interpretation of this problem around which meaningful progress can be made. This could mean looking *only* at numbers with the aforementioned prime decompositions, or looking to any numbers that satisfy the characterization constraints at the beginning of this post. The linked [**OEIS sequence**](https://oeis.org/A259980) is appreciated, although it is incomplete e.g. it is missing $92$ for the Frobenius number $91$, which has the desired factorizations: $(1,92)$, $(2,46)$, $(4, 23)$, each of which yield a solution: $(2,93)$, $(3, 47)$, and $(5, 24)$.

Comment: Do you want $N$ to only have 3 distinct factor pairs up to symmetry, or just 3 factor pairs $(a,b)$ satisfying $\gcd(a+1, b+1) = 1$ (but possibly more factor pairs not satisfying this)?

Comment: @wyoumans Good question. I am presently interested in *any* version of this problem that would be tractable! Either of the interpretations that you listed are fine with me, even as I realize that the latter would open up possibilities for the prime structure beyond just $p^2 \cdot q$ and $p^5$. $$ $$ (If there is little by way of responses posted within the next few days, I will edit my question to reflect the answer to your comment.)

Comment: I don't have any intuition to offer on this exact problem, but if you restrict it to the simplest case (say only 3 distinct factorizations) and enumerate the first so many examples with a simple program, you could compare against https://oeis.org/ and you might find some info on your sequence. At least this is how I would proceed.

Comment: What I mean is: If you were to find your sequence matches another it might give you some ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: If my mental calculations are correct, the sequence begins $12,18,20,32$. There is a sequence starting that way at oeis, but it's not what we want here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson if you mean https://oeis.org/A259980 the next number (44) seems to work as well (unless I'm making a dumb mistake). Maybe it's relevant.

Comment: @wyo, yes, $44$ works, but the definition of the sequence doesn't seem to me to make this either a subsequence or a supersequence of the one in question. It may be worth a closer look than what I gave it.

Comment: I agree, enumerating more values of the sequence would be helpful @gerrymyerson

Comment: @wyoumans Thanks for the OEIS sequence; notice that it is incomplete, as it is missing e.g. 92. [See edit to the post above.]

Comment: The OEIS sequence is missing $92$ because it is "Numbers that are 1+prime and have 4 proper divisors," and $91$ is not prime.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Right, I know why it's missing; I point it out only as an explicit example of a number satisfying the initial constraints that doesn't appear in that OEIS sequence.